# PHP - Absolute path to folders when creating a new subfolder

Tags: php, path, directory, document-root

I don't have much skills on PHP, but how do I define a root path on all files inside subfolders?
Let's take an example:
Images, css and other shared folders are on the site's root. If I create a subfolder called 'myfolder' and insert a php file that's quite similar to the root's main index.php, how do I prevent from updating all the relative paths with '../' one by one?

I guess this might be quite easy to solve, but I'm quite a newbie on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/yourfolder/style.css'; ?>`

Or you can define variable like $basePath and set it to http://yoursite.com/
and use this var in every place where you print images, styles, etc
`<?php echo $basePath . '/yourfolder/style.css'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

The magic constants

```
__FILE__
```

and

```
__DIR__
```

will probably be of help to you.  For example, to get the path to the file that needs to know where it's located:

```
$where_am_i = realpath (__DIR__);
```

So, "images" relative to the calling file would be $where_am_i/images, etc.

Comment: And I apologize, I can't get the underscores to appear properly.  Two before and two after "FILE" and "DIR"....